# unMerge and fill gaps VBA Running Slow

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Sheet wherein column "A" contains Serial numbers. One serial number may repeat to several rows. The cells in column "A" are merged [if more than one rows are appearing for One serial number]. I have made following macro to UN-merge these cells and repeat the serial number in subsequent blank rows until next serial number appears. The problem I am facing is that this macro is running very slow e.g. for a sheet containing 30,000 rows it may take a very long time. Is there a neat and less slower way to do it?

Here is the code I am using. Please guide.

```
Sub Unmerge_Cell()

Dim NumRows As Integer
Range("B2").Select

NumRows = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.UnMerge
    Range("A2").Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    For i = 1 To NumRows - 1           
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) = True Then
            ActiveCell.Select
     Selection.Copy
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        Else
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Activate
        End If    
    Next
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Regards

Comment: Avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate` as they both cause things to run very slowly, and there is always a better way to write the code.

Comment: @braX can you please suggest the alternatives.

Comment: Anytime you have a line of code that ends with `.Select` and the next line is `Selection` you just combine them... `Columns("A:A").UnMerge` does the same thing.

Comment: Also, you will want to learn how to fully qualify your Ranges instead of relying on whatever is active.

Comment: _**Thanks**_ @BraX

Comment: **1)** The Copy/Select is the code that is taking more time. **1.1)** You should use autofilter to filter for the desired value on the rows between your range and copy/paste them all at once. **1.2)** Or (a bit slower) select a non contiguous range and copy it and paste all at once. **2)** Copy/paste is slow, you could use just write the cell value.

Comment: Change `NumRows` to a long rather than an integer.  An integer can only hold values up to 32767 so will throw an error if you go too far over your 30000 rows.

Comment: 60% of our your questions are not marked as closed. Bad answers or bad user ?

Comment: My dear @Patrick I appreciate all the kind support everyone has given to me. The reason I did not reply all of them was because I left office and had no internet in transit. But that doesn't mean I don't appreciate all the kind help everyone has given here.

Comment: Please wait till tomorrow and I will reply to everyone after testing each solution. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the fastest solution, no loop, simple.

```
Sub unMerge()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("A:A").unMerge
    Range("A2:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]c"
    With Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        .Value = .Value  'convert formula to constant
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplyfy your code.  I haven't tested it in Excel ;-/

```
Sub Unmerge_Cell()

Dim NumRows As Integer
Dim i as Long

    NumRows = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    For i = 1 To NumRows - 1  
        If IsEmpty(Range("A2").Offset(i,0).Value) Then
            Range("A2").Offset(i,0).Value = Range("A2").Offset(i-1,0).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn off and turn on the screen updating when you macro is running

At the beginning on your code insert

```
application.screenupdating = false
```

And turn it on at the end

```
application.screenupdating = true
```